# Lotus Notes - Automatically export email to PDF on arrival

Tags: pdf, export, lotus-domino, lotus

Is it possible with Lotus Notes 8.5 to write a program (assuming an Agent) that will automatically export the email as a PDF document where the name of the document will be the subject line of the email?

I am being told by our lovely IT people that this will take months worth of effort to investigate, test and implement.

Surely there is a function that could be called to do this?

Can anyone please point me in the direction of a tutorial or help doc etc that I can read so I can have some more information to speak more authoritatively with our IT guys.

My intention is then to hand this information to the Domino Design team to ask them to build the function (without taking months to do so). :-)

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: You can do this with a Java agent that uses iText for instance. But what are you really trying to achieve? Do you really want a complete archive of mails as PDFs? Your admin people can also take a look at journaling if you are looking for a way to archive all mails.

Comment: There's some sample code for this technique here, which may be helpful:  http://www.openntf.org/Projects/codebin/codebin.nsf/0/63B9C615E6B53659862572B3003C0A07  You would have to integrate it into a correctly-designed agent, of course.  And even with this headstart, it could still take significant time.  And I completely agree with Per Henrik that you need to say a little bit more about what you want.  Why do you want to export these emails?  What emails do you want to export?  When do you want to export them?  Why specifically PDF? Where do you want these PDFs stored?  And more.

Comment: In production with heavy mail routing this will be literally killer app. Consider filter feature, that will invoke PDF conversion only for some users and some emails.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The reason we want to do this is because we have an "Imaging" system where all of our snail-mail is scanned by an external mail house and using OCR is automatically attaches the images to a client record in our system. We want to do the same with emails, but the Lotus Notes team say this will take months of effort. If I get the emails as PDF's I can write a routine to attach them to our client records just like I did with the snail-mail images.

Answer (score 1):

There is a third party application called PD4ML which allows you to export to PDF format. They also supply samples on how to do this in the Notes client.

http://www.pd4ml.com/lotus.htm

You would need to create an agent that runs on new mail arriving.

There is also some sample code on SearchDomino.

http://searchdomino.techtarget.com/tip/Converting-Lotus-Notes-Domino-Web-pages-to-PDF-files-with-a-Java-agent

Answer (score 0):

Alternative option is also available, user can save Lotus Notes email to PDF format through third party Lotus Notes to PDF tool with 100% secure manner. 
http://www.lotusnotestooutlookexpress.com/lotus-notes-export-email-to-pdf

you can read email conversion process and other useful detail of software in PDF format
http://www.lotusnotestoexchange.com/guide-for-lotus-notes-to-pdf-conversion.pdf

Answer (score 0):

There's an "industry standard" tool to export Lotus Notes documents to PDF.
This tool is Swing PDF Converter.
Please check it out here: http://www.swingsoftware.com/pdf-converter/overview

Swing PDF Converter supports Lotus Notes format emails (RTF) and HTML - MIME email conversion to PDF.
There is also advanced support for pdf document naming, single document conversion, batch conversion, document archiving option and even support for automatic upload to document repositories such as MS Sharepoint, Alfresco, Filenet, etc..